# Android Listview item Partially Visible

Tags: android, listview

i created a custom Listview Adapter with ViewHolder and used it with a ListFragment, for some reason i dont know, the last Listview item does not render totally

Adapter Code

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);



    } else {
        // recycle the already inflated view
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // update the item view
    ListItem item = getItem(position);
    if(item!=null){
        viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(item.title);
        viewHolder.tvDescription.setText(item.description);
    }


    return convertView;
}

/**
 * The view holder design pattern prevents using findViewById()
 * repeatedly in the getView() method of the adapter.
 *
 * @see http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder
 */
private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivIcon;
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvDescription;
}
}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@color/frame_background"
android:padding="5dp" >

<!-- the innner view - provides the white rectangle -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame" >

    <!-- the icon view -->
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="desc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <!-- the container view for the title and description -->
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <!-- the title view -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <!-- the description view -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:padding="3dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Fragment code since i am using a ListFragment

```
Public class IntroFragment extends ListFragment {
private List<ListItem> mItems;        // ListView items list

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // initialize the items list
    mItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    Resources resources = getResources();
    String[] factfiles=resources.getStringArray(R.array.SunFacts);
  mItems.add(new ListItem(resources.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher), factfiles[i], factfiles[i])); }


    // initialize and set the list adapter
    setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
    getListView().setDivider(null);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // retrieve theListView item
    ListItem item = mItems.get(position);

    // do something
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

the Screenshot below shows what i mean,notice the white edge of a new Listview item at the bottom,
and the listview will not scroll anymore.
[Screenshot (cant upload it here due to rep points)](http://i62.tinypic.com/10rsfgo.png)

Thanks in advance..this is already driving me half bean and bananas..

Comment: please update the xml code that contains your listview

Comment: Please post the Code where you add Fragment to Container and also Post xml for Container.

Comment: found the culprit, @HradeshKumar ,my RelativeView for the activity was poorly constructed.fixed it..thanks